# Maintaining order in parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, geolocation, data-manipulation

We are implementing a system where a thousands requests will come to our queue in an order and we are processing the data parallel, when we do that we are losing the order that we received, but how do we maintain an order if we do parallel processing.

for ex:
An uber driver is sending his location every 10s to the queue with lat and lang, and it will be in the order, but when we process the data parallelly, we are losing the data order. how do we prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall requirements aren't clear to me, but it seems simple enough to add an incrementing ID to each inbound request.  That would let you (re)order processed data so it matches your inbound order.